# Is there a way to serialize data across machines?

Tags: java, serialization

Wondering if there is a way to serialize data to be accessed by multiple machines independently.

From my understanding, serializing data creates a .ser file where the byte representation of the data is saved locally, or on that particular machine. Is there a similar way to save this data so that multiple unrelated machines can access it, without sending any files to them?

One machine saves data, and another is able to access the data they saved without directly contactin (via email etc) the other machine

Comment: Any solution that moves data from one machine to another machine is going to require "direct contact". Whether it's a shared file over the network, a TCP download, a database connection, etc. Can you clarify why you don't wan't the other machines to have to "directly contact" the machine with the files?

Comment: Java serialization with ".ser" files is only one of many means of serialization--and *any* coordination between machines has to serialize the data so that it can be transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the data to a database, which other machines can read from.

Or you can set up a web API on the machine with the data that other machines can access when they want it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. In one of my school projects, we used sockets to send objects over the network.

The majority of the serialization work is done in the server module.

It can be found here: https://gitlab.com/cs-321-group-project/cs-321-group-project